# Given a Timestamp - How to return the nearest Unit and Metric,,, ex: 13 mins, 1 hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

given a timestamp, I could like to have a method that returns the correct unit (secs, hours, minutes) and the correct metric for that unit.

Examples, for a timestamp:

```
1 sec ago - Unit: SEC, Metric: 1
20 secs ago - Unit: SECS, Metric: 20
1 hour ago - Unit: HOUR, Metric: 1
3 hour ago - Unit: HOURS, Metric: 3
25 hours ago - Unit: DAY, Metric: 1
50 hours ago - Unit: DAYS, Metric: 2
```

For this method I only need to go support, sec, hours and days. Not months. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the logic is already as a helper in Rails: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words

Something like this maybe:

def words_and_units(from_time, to_time = 0)

from_time = from_time.to_time if from_time.respond_to?(:to_time)
  to_time = to_time.to_time if to_time.respond_to?(:to_time)
  distance_in_minutes = (((to_time - from_time).abs)/60).round
  distance_in_seconds = ((to_time - from_time).abs).round

```
case distance_in_minutes
  when 0..1

    case distance_in_seconds
      when 0..59   then {:metric => distance_in_seconds, :unit => 'SEC'}
      else             {:metric => 1, :unit => 'MIN'}
    end

  when 2..44           then {:metric => distance_in_minutes, :unit => 'MIN'}
  when 45..89          then {:metric => 1, :unit => 'HOUR'}
  when 90..1439        then {:metric => (distance_in_minutes.to_f / 60.0).round, :unit => 'HOUR'}
  when 1440..2529      then {:metric => 1, :unit => 'DAY'}
  when 2530..43199     then {:metric => (distance_in_minutes.to_f / 1440.0).round, :unit => 'DAY'}
  else
    raise WayToLongError
end
```

end

Comment: Thanks but how do you access the :metric :unit variables given this func?

Comment: You get a hash back, so something like myvar = words_and_units(Time.now) => {:metric => 1, :unit => 'SEC'} so then you can use myvar[:metric] or myvar[:unit]

Comment: Or you could use a convenience methods to extract it for you like def metric(from_time) words_and_units(from_time)[:metric] end to wrap it up nice and tight